# How to completely reinstall virtualenv on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a broken installation of `virtualenv` on Ubuntu 20.04.4, and I want to reinstall it completely new. I tried to remove the current installation with

```
sudo apt remove virtualenv
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove virtualenv 
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove virtualenv
```

but the file

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

still exists. And when I try to create a virtualenv with

```
virtualenv venv
```

I get an error

```
/home/adietz/.local/bin/virtualenv
```

(even I removed EVERY `virtualenv` from `/usr/bin`)!!

Something seems totally mixed up. How can I fix this?

When I open a new terminal and try to create a virtualenv it tells me:

```
Command 'virtualenv' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python3-virtualenv
```

But running this command does not solve any issues, as when I run the above command, I get the above error again.

Additional infos:

- `which virtualenv` returns nothing
- `mkvirtualenv` returns `ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path`
- python version is 3.8.10

Comment: I tried the three remove commands I added to the question. They do not seem to remove anything. Problem still exists

Answer (score -1):

The following trick is a workaround. Instead of using `virtualenv` I create a virtual environment as follows

```
python -m venv myvenv
```

But that does not solve my `virtualenvwrapper` issue.